# How can I copy a list of recipients in GMail?

Tags: gmail

Every place that GMail lists recipients, they are mangled in some way.  Either they are listed like this:

- `John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>`
- `Alice <alice@foo.bar>`

Like this:

- John Doe (@gmail)
- Alice (@foo)

Or like this:
[image]

I can not find a single place where emails are listed in a cleartext way that can be copied to a clipboard.  Is it possible to access the actual text content of the recipient field in GMail?

Here is an example of a list of emails: `johndoe@gmail.com, alice@foo.bar, a@b.c`

Just spaces would work too: `johndoe@gmail.com alice@foo.bar a@b.c`

Semi-colons also work: `johndoe@gmail.com; alice@foo.bar; a@b.c`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an example of your desired result based on your example addresses

Comment: I've edited the question to include three examples of working recipient field formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the original message:

1. Open the email message on Gmail (https://mail.google.com).
2. Click the **More** (three dots) button at the message's top right, then click **Show Original**.

The above will open a window showing the most critical fields, a button to download the email message, and a section showing the whole content as plain text.

Comment: Unfortunately, emails are still listed in a way that isn't just emails, so it's not ideal for anyone who's trying to get a simple email list.  Fortunately, it can be copied and pasted into another gmail so it fits my need.

Comment: @LibrarySeph I recommend that you consider learning about computer command writing, usually referred to as coding and scripting. Using JavaScript and regular expressions on your web browser's developers tools console, you can easily get the list of email addresses. Other options are to use apps like Notepad++, Visual Code Studio, among many that are available for free.

Comment: Oh I know.  20+ years of dev experience.  Given the emails I'm working with, I wouldn't even need full validator `[\w\d]+@[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+` would totally suffice.  But my position is such I need to avoid leaving userland.  At some point I will be passing my librarian role onto someone else, and they likely won't have my tech expertise.  I don't mind being an accelerationist for my own projects, but things like this should be at least somewhat accessible.

Comment: @LibrarySeph Thanks for sharing. Gmail web app is both a "light email client" and an "innovative tool" as some tasks might be done in a "novel way", *the Google way*. While Google attempts to make things "easier," it might be counterintuitive for some experienced computer users.

Comment: Whenever you have time, please read [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691) (a \[faq] from [meta.se])

Comment: I've been on stack exchange with my non library account since about 2010.  I know well the XY problem premise, but I also don't agree with it.  As pragmatic as it is to revolve everything around the core problem, it closes off exploration, discovery, and creative approaches.  Pursuing bad ideas is very important to learning the shape of them, and it's also how novel solutions are found.  Besides, in the next decade the only XY answer will be "you need to get better at telling AI what you want."  "you didn't specify well enough."